# Paypal api scheduled task php

Tags: php, paypal

I need to set up a paypal payment API on a website i am working .I have email id of both the payee and payer but do not have any API signature or username of payee.
Basicaly every user on my site have to paid according to a payment option they select.
For example if a user on my site select that he wants to get paid on every tuesday of the week.SO how can i achieve this without any user action?Because i have to pay user on every tuesday .it's like a scheduled task.But i don't know how paypal handles it.
May be paypal recurring api can be useful. but i am not getting the right idea to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link ,Hope PayPal Authorization & Capture method will be suitable for you

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture